# Lazy loading for ManyToOne in hibernate not working

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, lazy-loading, criteria, many-to-one

I want to use a ManyToOne join with hibernate and kotlin without loding the joined entity by default.

```
@Entity 
class Author { 
  @Id 
  var id = 0L 
  lateinit var name: String
   
  @OneToMany 
  lateinit var books: List<Book>
  ...
}


@Entity 
class Book { 
  @Id 
  var id = 0L 
  lateinit var title: String

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
  @JoinColumn(name = "author_id") 
  lateinit var author: Author
  ... 
}
```

All entities are open.

If I load the books with

```
criteriaQuery.select(rootBook)
```

for every book the author also loads by default.

How can I prevent the author from loading except when addressing it?

I also tried

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)/@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)/@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.FALSE)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId

@Proxy(lazy = true) // As annotation for the class
```

in hibernate I enabled

```
enable_lazy_load_no_trans
enhancer.enableLazyInitialization
```

and I added

```
org.hibernate.orm.tooling:hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin
```

to Gradle